# How to do dynamic eager loading based on the value of one of the model's properties?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, eager-loading

Let's say we use the same table schema for saving purchased products of orders for website A and B. Databases for A and B locate in different servers. So 2 database connections are defined.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `order_products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  # other columns...
);
```

And we are building an application for analysing all orders in different platforms. We have imported and saved the data in another summary table, schema being like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE `summary_orders` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'site_a', # 'site_a', 'site_b'
  # other columns...
);
```

To access purchased products in different platforms, we define 2 identical classes but in different namespaces:

```php
<?php

namespace Path\To\Class\SiteA;

class OrderProduct extends SiteABaseModel
{
    
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace Path\To\Class\SiteB;

class OrderProduct extends SiteBBaseModel
{
    
}
```

To fetch purchased products of orders, in SummaryOrder class, we define a relation `products`:

```php
class SummaryOrder extends Model
{
    protected $sourcesToConnections = [
        'source_a' => 'connection_a',
        'source_b' => 'connection_b'
    ];
    
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function products()
    {
        $namespace = sprintf("Path\To\Class\%s", ucfirst($this->source));
        $class = "$namespace\OrderProduct";
        // $this->source has no value here when calling with()
        $connection = $this->sourcesToConnections[$this->source];
        return $this->setConnection($connection)->hasMany($class, 'id', 'order_id');
    }

    //...
}
```

Then we want to fetch all data from `summary_orders` like so

```php
$orders = SummaryOrder::query()
    ->with(['products:product_id,order_id'])
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($order) {
    // prepare more stuff
    });
```

The above call is gonna fail because when Laravel is building a query and calling `products()` in `SummaryOrder`, there is in fact no SummaryOrder instance hence `$this->source` has no value. So we end up with undefined index error when accessing `$sourcesToConnections`: `$this->sourcesToConnections[$this->source]`.

A "solution" is dont-do eager loading at the cost of performance:

```php
$orders = SummaryOrder::query()
    ->with(['products:product_id,order_id'])
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($order) {
    // prepare more stuff
        $order->products;
    });
```

Apparently this is not ideal. So my question is, how can I keep `SummaryOrder::products()` as flexible as possible, but also keep performance gain `with()` gives me?

Comment: Why are you using `query()` rather than `SummaryOrder::with(...)`?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter behind the scenes Laravel will call `query()` / `newQuery() ` to create query builder instance. I explictly type here just for PhpStorm, so it can give me autocompletion, nothing special, lol

Comment: Yeah it's just redundant is why I asked, makes sense for the IDE hinting though.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Thinking further on this, I'm not sure your approach is possible because eager loading executes a `WHERE IN (...)` on the id of the related table. Since your relation is split between databases, it's 1) possible to have duplicate primary keys in the `order_products` tables of A and B, and 2) the the `WHERE IN (...)` clause wouldn't have anyway to know which value belongs to which table of A or B.

The closest answer I can come up with is to actually split the product relation into separate ones for each "source".

```
public function productsA()
{
    $connection = 'connection-to-a';
    return $this->setConnection($connection)->hasMany('Path\To\Class\SiteA\OrderProduct', 'id', 'order_id');
}

public function productsB()
{
    $connection = 'connection-to-b';
    return $this->setConnection($connection)->hasMany('Path\To\Class\SiteB\OrderProduct', 'id', 'order_id');
}


$orders = SummaryOrder::query()
    ->with([
        'productA:id,product_id,order_id',
        'productB:id,product_id,order_id'
    ])
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($order) {
        // prepare more stuff
    });
```

Note the addition of `id` to the eager loading above. The docs on eager loading specific columns state:

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

Obviously not as efficient or clean as a single dynamic relation, but it does avoid the N+1 problem you're facing at the cost of 4 queries vs 2. Interesting question, I'll be looking into this some more!

---

There is one caveat for anyone who wants to adopt this method: If order IDs are likely to be identical in more than one source, you have to manually handle dataset like so:

```php
$orders = SummaryOrder::query()
    ->with([
        'productA:id,product_id,order_id',
        'productB:id,product_id,order_id'
    ])
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($order) {
        $data = $order;

        if ($order->source === 'site_a') {
            $data['products'] = $order->productA
        }

        if ($order->source === 'site_b') {
            $data['products'] = $order->productB;
        }

        unset($data['productA']);
        unset($data['productB']);

        // do other things
        return $data;
    });
```

That said, if you are assured that order IDs are unique across sources, you can safely ignore the change above.

Comment: good catch on order ID. In reality our order IDs are alphanumeric strings so do worry about potential duplicate primary keys in A and B. Order ID column definition posted above is misleading, but you can ignore it

Comment: @Carter If order IDs are alpha numeric - why not use uuid as ID? Even if both sites are in production, I guess adding a uuid column can help and then define relationships on uuid columns can solve the issue of duplicate ids while querying at the least. Just a thought

Comment: sorry for typo, should be "so do not worry about potential duplicate primary keys in A and B".
I think the format of order ID is not the main issue in this application, because at the end of the day, when importing data, we have to use column `source` to distinguish where orders come from, right?

Comment: Correct, source isn't accessible in the relationship method. But lazy eager loading, as pointed out by @Donkarnash, solves this when no dynamic connection is involved. However, I still think there is the issue of `WHERE IN (1, 2, 3)` and associating each value with the respective connection. I'm really curious what comes of this question. I think my original split relation approach might be as close as we can get using multiple databases.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter  I have to say this is the only one solution I've got so far. So I upvoted it. I also edited the answer to take account of the extreme case where order IDs are identical in more than one source. This answer should be bug-free right now.

Comment: hi @Brian Lee excellent +1, does eager loading **always** use `WHERE IN?` THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

How about Lazy eager loading

```php
$orders = SummaryOrder::query()->get();

//Lazy eager loading - doesn't create N+1 problem
//executes just 1 query just like with()
$orders->load(['products:product_id, order_id']);

$orders->map(function ($order) {
    // prepare more stuff
        $order->products;
    });
```

For eg: lets say we have:

**Post belongsTo User (author)**

**Post hasMany Comment**

both way relationships are defined in respective Model classes

Let's test in a route with closure function - welcome route

```php
Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
    $posts = Post::with('author')->get();
    $posts->load('comments')->map(function ($post) {
        // dump($post->author->name);
    });

    return view('welcome');
});
```

The queries as seen in debug bar

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the N+1 problem that using `with` does. One query is executed to get all the `SummaryOrder` records, then each iteration of map executes another query to load that model's relations, so the performance gains the OP wants are not realized.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Lazy Eager Loading outside the map function executes just one query same as `with` does eliminating N+1 problem. Probably this is what @Carter is looking for.

Comment: I have my doubts this works, mainly because of how eager loading uses `WHERE IN ()` to load the related records. How would the query know which connection to use for each id in `WHERE IN (1, 2, 3)`, for example. Does 1 belong to products in site A or B, same thing for 2, 3, etc.

Comment: I tested it and it works. You can try on any dummy schema with seed data

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Have updated answer with example query and status in debug bar

Comment: Any chance you would push your working example to a public repo? I've been trying to get this working locally using the setup described by OP as closely as possible and cannot get it to work. I'm curious to see what you did to manage the dynamic connection switching and eager loading.

Comment: hi @Donkarnash, thank you for the reply, but I think you missed the most important point here: a dynamic `products()`. In your case, a dynamic `comments()`. calling `comments()` is across models and databse connections, based on the value of some property in yout `Post` model, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Carter Ahh yes. Dynamic products() is the spoiler here:). @DigitalDrifter solution is probably the apparent one. Unless of course if you can import all data and have a `source` column just like multi tenancy

Comment: @DigitalDrifter  I think that I should remove the answer as it doesn't solve the issue in question. What do you say - just asking because you have referenced in one of your your comment. You may include pseudo code for lazy eager loading in your answer and remove the referencing comment after that I can delete my answer.